# Combining Phonegap event 'deviceready' with jQuery (Phonegap build)

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm pretty new to Phonegap - and I'm having some startup issues.

I'm trying to fire a function on deviceready, but it never occurs for some reason.

My html markup is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<title>Masonite Dashboard</title>
<link href="js/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="js/jquery-mobile/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

In my file: jquery.main.js I've got the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // some code here 
});
 function onDeviceReady() {
         alert("device ready fired!");
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated :)

Comment: you need to include cordova.js before jquery.main.js

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick reply :)

Sorry for being somewhat slow perhaps... but I thought, when using Phonegap Build, one didn't need to include phonegap.js (which from what I've read is more or less the same as cordova.js?), as it is added on phonegap build compile ?

Or am I totally off track here? :)

Tried adding cordova.js anyways ( from:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/cordova-js/master/src/cordova.js ), and it throws an Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined  :(

Comment: it seems that you need to remove the cordova.js or phonegap.js but you need to keep the script tag in your html [build phonegap](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/introduction_getting_started.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Build)

Comment: Oh my..that solved it... Thanks a million! :)